# Date and Time Objects in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to use the DateObject in Mathematica to calculate the difference in times between two cities.

How do I convert the DateObject and TimeObject output to numerical values so I can manipulate them and plot them?

Comment: In the docs https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html the first example under the orange Properties and Relations shows that AbsoluteTime[DateObject[]] will convert the DateObject into the number of seconds since  January 1 1900. Maybe that will get you part of the way where you want to go and give you some ideas what to try to get the rest of the way there

Comment: Thank you... The following code generates a table of sunrises:  sunriseTable=Table[Sunrise[GeoPosition[Toronto],DateObject[{2022,1,day+d,0,0,0,},TimeZone->-5]],{d,1,days}].   The issue is that the values returned in the table do not seem to be DateObjects  ....  Which is why when I do AbsoluteTime[DateObject[sunriseTable], Mathematica says "cannot be interpreted as a date or time input".

Comment: So my suspicion is that DateObject doesn't return a date object, but some other form of output.  I can't find any documentation on this.  For example, if you try to subtract on of the sunriseTable data points from another it doesn't work.

Comment: Since you question what DateObject returns I try to manually get the first item for that Table with  DateObject[{2022,1,day+1,0,0,0,},TimeZone->-5] where I substitute 1 for d like your Table should do in the first step. MMA doesn't seem to understand. And your arguments to DateObject don't seem to look like any of the examples in the documentation. Are you assuming your variable day has some value you have not shown me? (I often think these new abstract functions cause more problems for users than the old way of just giving literal values for things.)

Comment: There is no need to convert the dates into numerical values. See [`DateDifference`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateDifference.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain numerical values using `DateList` e.g.

```
d = Today
t = TimeObject[Now]
o = DateObject[d, t]
{dt, tm} = TakeDrop[DateList[o], 3]
DateString[o, {"DayName", ", ", "DayShort", " ", "MonthName"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

By putting your code into comments you've made it very difficult to be certain what you have done, for example, it's no surprise that the expression

`GeoPosition[Toronto]`

is unevaluated and that the enclosing expressions do not do what you want them to do.  Nevertheless, guessing at what you might be trying to do ...

If I execute the following:

```
sList = Table[Sunrise[Entity["City", {"Toronto", "Ontario", "Canada"}], 
  DateObject[{2022, 1, 9 + i, 0, 0, 0}]], {i, 0, 9}]
```

my Mathematica (v12.something on Mac) returns a list of 10 `DateObjects`, starting with

```
DateObject[{2022, 1, 9, 12, 50}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 0.]
```

And if I execute

```
AbsoluteTime /@ sList
```

MMA returns a list of 10 absolute times.

Now, set

```
t1 = DateObject[{2022, 1, 9, 12, 50}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 0.]
```

and, using another city ...

```
t2 = Sunrise[Entity["City", {"Liverpool", "Liverpool", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
  DateObject[{2022, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0}]]
```

then

```
DateDifference[t1, t2]
```

returns

```
Quantity[-0.18472222222222223, "Days"]
```

You'll notice that I have not bothered with the time zone for the `DateObject` (irrelevant for calculating differences between cities) and I have not wrapped `Toronto` in `GeoPosition`, MMA is smart enough to not need that assistance.

Comment: The above worked perfectly.  Changing the Date Object to an absolute time allowed me to manipulate the values of milliseconds without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The objective of the file is to calculate the numbers of hours of daylight in Toronto and Edmonton.  First, create a counter called "daysElapsed"

`daysElapsed=365;`

Next, create a table of sunrises and sunsets.  These are returned Date Objects / Quantities.

```
sunriseToList = 
  Table[Sunrise[Entity["City", {"Toronto", "Ontario", "Canada"}], 
    DateObject[{2022, 1, 1 + i, 0, 0, 0}]], {i, 0, daysElapsed}];

sunsetToList = 
  Table[Sunset[Entity["City", {"Toronto", "Ontario", "Canada"}], 
    DateObject[{2022, 1, 1 + i, 0, 0, 0}]], {i, 0, daysElapsed}];
```

Using the function, AbsoluteTime, convert the two lists of Date Objects into times in milliseconds.  This allows you to manipulate the data easily.

```
sunrisenumTo = AbsoluteTime /@ sunriseToList;

sunsetnumTo = AbsoluteTime /@ sunsetToList;
```

Subtracting the time of sunrise from the time of sunset gives the total time of daylight.

```
hoursoflightTo = N[(sunsetnumTo - sunrisenumTo)/60/60];
```

Repeat the above process for the next city: Edmonton

```
sunriseEdList = 
  Table[Sunrise[Entity["City", {"Edmonton", "Alberta", "Canada"}], 
    DateObject[{2022, 1, 1 + i, 0, 0, 0}]], {i, 0, daysElapsed}];

sunsetEdList = 
  Table[Sunset[Entity["City", {"Edmonton", "Alberta", "Canada"}], 
    DateObject[{2022, 1, 1 + i, 0, 0, 0}]], {i, 0, daysElapsed}];

sunrisenumEd = AbsoluteTime /@ sunriseEdList;

sunsetnumEd = AbsoluteTime /@ sunsetEdList;

hoursoflightEd = N[(sunsetnumEd - sunrisenumEd)/60/60];

t = hoursoflightTo - hoursoflightEd;
```

The first plot below shows the difference in hours of sunlight.  As Edmonton is in the far north, it gets less light in the winter and way more in the summer.

```
plotT = ListLinePlot[hoursoflightTo - hoursoflightEd]
```

[Difference in hours of light between cities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRBAR.png)

This plots the hours of light for each city over 365 days.

```
ListPlot[{hoursoflightEd, hoursoflightTo}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[Hours of Light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYXIc.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).